# Copy paste rows from one table to another: Getting runtime Error 9

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, trying to teach myself. I want to copy rows in one table and paste them into a new table on another sheet. At first, I wanted to copy the rows to the bottom of the original table, and this script worked perfectly:
    '

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range
    'Set a = Selection
    'For Each b In a.Rows
    'Set LastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
    'b.Copy
'LastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        'Next
```

But when I tried to simply change the destination to another sheet and table, I got Runtime Error 9, Subscript Out of Range.

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range
Set a = Selection
    For Each b In a.Rows
        b.Copy
            Set LastRow = Worksheets _ 
("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add
        LastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next
```

I've tried a whole bunch of things to fix this and I can't seem to get it right. Help appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Set LastRow`? Why are you doing `ListRows.Add` there? If that does work though, I think the next line is where you're getting the error.  Just try `LastRow.PasteSpecial ..`.

Comment: `a.Rows` and `a` are the same thing ... using `a.Rows` just adds another element of confusion for anyone reading the code

Comment: you always have to state which line causes the error, otherwise people are just guessing .... `LastRow` is a range object, so your code is effectively `Range.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` ..... you want this instead `LastRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Comment: Hello BruceWayne, I'm getting the Error 9 in the second macro, in the line starting with "Set LastRow."  I was trying to copy the rows to the bottom of the new table. I confess I borrowed some of the code from a sample. My interpretation is that Set LastRow creates the rows *and* sets a name so that it can be used in the last line. Simply put, all I want to do now is copy and paste the rows into the second table, anywhere.

Comment: Hello jsotola, thanks for the tips. I just tried changing to LastRow.PasteSpecial etc and I still get the error. The Error 9 is in the line starting with "Set LastRow" and I think I am failing to correctly point to the table on the second sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. What is your declaration for Lastrow?
It copies the rows I selected in 'Table1' from Sheet1 and appends it to the 'Table1' In Sheet2.

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range
   Dim Lastrow As Variant
   Set a = Selection
    For Each b In a.Rows
     b.Copy
     Set Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add
        Lastrow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next
```

Comment: Valli, I just tried your script and I still get Error 9, Subscript out of Range, in the line beginning with "Set Lastrow"

Comment: Did you put it inside sub somename() and then finish it with end sub(). Because I just copied the logic..

Comment: Did you put it inside sub somename() and then finish it with end sub(). Because I just copied the logic..

Comment: Yes, my code is part of a larger piece that begins with Sub and ends with End Sub.

Comment: Can you try this piece of code alone?. It works perfect for me

Comment: So you can figure it out if its on the rest of the code

Comment: Valli, I'm not sure how to do that because "Set a = Selection" refers to a selection acquired in previous lines of code. I have tested the previous code and it works correctly to acquire the selection. The line that is highlighted with the error is the one beginning with "Set LastRow." I have tried many different ways to express the destination and I keep getting that error.

Comment: Ok, I manually Selected few rows in table1 and then ran the script. I too got same error initially when I tried your code. Then I declared Lastrows as variant. Then I did not get any error.

Comment: Valli, I can't account for it ... I copied your code exactly and I get the error.

Comment: That's interesting. Can I see your sheet sample? If you can.. Am just curious to learn

Comment: I'd be glad to ... but I've looked all over the page and don't see a way to send an attachment.

Comment: upload somewhere in onedrive or googledrive and Ping the link